# What's the difference between negative and indefinite judgment?

Tags: kant

I was reading critique of pure reason (the chapter that deals with the categories of judgments) I can not distinguish the difference between a negative judgment and an indefinite judgment, for example between :

- Kant is not English (Negative)
- Kant is non-English (Limitation/Indefinite)

This may seem silly but I can't get the distinction : as for me this is the exact same thing.

Comment: Hello. Could you a more precise reference and/or quotation? I don't see that Kant wrote about " indefinite" judgments.

Answer (score 1):

The actual sentence as such doesn't matter; it's a certain perspective that the sentence can carry - the negative or indefinite judgement; and it's keyed by the form of the sentence.

A positive judgement affirms the positive: Kant is German. Similarly a negative judgement affirms the negative: Kant is not German.

The first sentence says he is German but says nothing about what else he could be - he may have dual nationality for instance; similarly the second sentence though saying he is not German, doesn't say what he is. It's in this sense the sentences are seen as indefinite.